# How to create a custom list and \item element?

Tags: cross-referencing, lists

I would like to create my own list environment with custom `\item` element, with a custom tag *myitem*, that takes an optional parameter (the *2,7,6* in my example). It should be a numbered list. I should be able to reference it.

This is basically what I want:

Proposed latex code:

```
Look at \ref{a}, and \ref{b}
\begin{mylist}
\myitem[2] \label{a} lorum ipsum lorum ipsum
\myitem[7] lorum ipsum etc.
\myitem[6] \label{b} lorum ipsum etc.
\end{mylist}
```

The output should be:

Look at **myPrefix**-2-1, and **myPrefix**-6-3
**myPrefix**-2-1 lorum ipsum lorum ipsum
**myPrefix**-7-2 lorum ipsum etc.
**myPrefix**-6-3 lorum ipsum etc.

Should I clean up the question a bit more?

So far with Tom and egreg's help, I have the following code:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{label*=RQ\arabic*:~,ref=RQ\arabic*}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myitem[1][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \item\relax
  \else
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{RQ#1}%
    \item[RQ#1:~]
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

All I now need is for the label referencing to work as stated in my edited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to let **enumitem** do some job

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{label*=RQ\arabic*:~,ref=RQ\arabic*}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myitem[1][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \item\relax
  \else
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{RQ#1}%
    \item[RQ#1:~]
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{mylist}
\myitem\label{x} x
\myitem[3]\label{y} y
\myitem z
\end{mylist}
--\ref{x}--\ref{y}--
\end{document}
```

The complicated conditional is just to make correct references also for `\myitem[x]`. Some other code can be added for getting also hyperlinks.

Check **enumitem**'s documentation for how to change the other list parameters (indentation, label width and so on).

## Addition

To get the numbering scheme you're proposing, change the code into

```
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mylist*}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mylist*]{label=\mylistprefix-\mylistopt-\arabic*:~,
  ref=\mylistprefix-\mylistopt-\arabic*}
\makeatletter
\let\mylistopt\relax % to keep enumitem happy
\newcommand\myitem[1][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \def\mylistopt{0}% no optional argument to \myitem
  \else
    \def\mylistopt{#1}% optional argument to \myitem
  \fi
    \item\relax}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{mylist}[1][myPrefix]
  {\def\mylistprefix{#1}\begin{mylist*}}
  {\end{mylist*}}
```

You call it as

```
\begin{mylist}
\myitem[2] \label{a} lorum ipsum lorum ipsum
\myitem[7] lorum ipsum etc.
\myitem[6] \label{b} lorum ipsum etc.
\myitem ll
\end{mylist}
```

or

```
\begin{mylist}[RQ]
\myitem[2] \label{a} lorum ipsum lorum ipsum
\myitem[7] lorum ipsum etc.
\myitem[6] \label{b} lorum ipsum etc.
\myitem ll
\end{mylist}
```

to get `RQ` as the prefix.

## A different implementation

Suppose you want the numbering of items to be unique for the whole document, but that you also want to decide at some point from where to start numbering. A key-value interface is more suitable:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,keyval}
\makeatletter
\define@key{vort3xlist}{prefix}{\def\mylistprefix{#1}}
\define@key{vort3xlist}{start}{\setcounter{mylistcnt}{#1}}
\makeatother

\newcounter{mylistcnt}
\newlist{mylist*}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mylist*]{label=\mylistprefix-\mylistopt-\arabic{mylistcnt}:~,
  ref=\mylistprefix-\mylistopt-\arabic{mylistcnt}}
\makeatletter
\let\mylistopt\relax
\newcommand\myitem[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{mylistcnt}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \def\mylistopt{0}%
  \else
    \def\mylistopt{#1}%
  \fi
    \item\relax}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{mylist}[1][]
  {\setkeys{vort3xlist}{prefix=RQ}%change here your default prefix
   \setkeys{vort3xlist}{#1}%
   \begin{mylist*}}
  {\end{mylist*}}

\begin{document}
Look at \ref{a}, and \ref{b}
\begin{mylist}[start=3,prefix=XYZ]
\myitem[2] \label{a} lorum ipsum lorum ipsum
\myitem[7] lorum ipsum etc.
\myitem[6] \label{b} lorum ipsum etc.
\myitem \label{x} ll
\end{mylist}
Here's a second list
\begin{mylist}
\myitem[2] \label{c} lorum ipsum lorum ipsum
\myitem[7] lorum ipsum etc.
\myitem[6] \label{d} lorum ipsum etc.
\myitem \label{y} ll
\end{mylist}
\ref{c}, \ref{d}

\ref{x} and \ref{y}
\end{document}
```

The keys accepted are `prefix` and `start`, as you can see in the first `mylist`.

Comment: This might not be the right place to do it, but could you perhaps explain some more on why each item in the conditional is used? Or give me a link I can read up on how you reached this piece of code?

Comment: I would like \ref{x} /\ref{y} to show the reference as RQ-3-1, where the 1 is the enumerated counter. I tried using \arabic and \arabic*, but I have no idea what I'm doing, and struggling to find documentation on advanced topics as this. If the item was made without a parameter, it should be RQ-0-1. I would also like the list items to display as RQ-param-itemcounter, instead of RQparam.

Comment: @Vort3x: it's not very clear what numbering scheme you have in mind. Maybe you can edit your question to make it more explicit.

Comment: <>@egreg: I just totally reworked the question to make it cleaner and clearer.

Comment: Btw how do you do the @Vort3x: ? with the ':' and ' '

Comment: @Vort3x Just write `@Vort3x`; the colon is optional. I've added the code for the new numbering scheme.

Comment: Thanks egreg, you have been extremely helpful. This is now perfect.

Comment: @egregI would just like to know how to make the counter global, or set it to what I want. I know you use \setcounter{\value{reqcounter}} or something, I just don't know where to use it.

Answer (score 4):

You can quite easily define your own lists. Put that in an environment, define a custom item. Here you go (you don't need the `geometry` package, I just hate to waste too much space):

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}

\newcounter{itemnumber}

\newenvironment{mylist}[1]{% Prefix
\setcounter{itemnumber}{0}%
\begin{list}{\textbf{#1}}{}%
}{\end{list}}

\newcommand{\myentry}[2]{% Number, Text
\stepcounter{itemnumber}%
\item \textit{#1}: \theitemnumber\ #2%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}{myPrefix}
    \myentry{2}{lorem ipsum adin}
    \myentry{7}{lorem ipsum dwa}
    \myentry{6}{lorem ipsum tri}
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** For referencable entries you can use `hyperref`s `hyperlink` and `hypertarget`:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newcounter{itemnumber}

\newenvironment{mylist}[1]{% Prefix
\setcounter{itemnumber}{0}%
\begin{list}{\textbf{#1}}{}%
}{\end{list}}

\newcommand{\myentry}[2]{% Number, Text
\stepcounter{itemnumber}%
\item \textit{#1}: \theitemnumber\ #2%
}

\newcommand{\mylinkentry}[3]{% Number, Text, linklabel
\stepcounter{itemnumber}%
\item \textit{#1}: \theitemnumber\ \hypertarget{#3}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\hrule

\begin{mylist}{myPrefix}
    \myentry{2}{lorem ipsum adin}
    \myentry{7}{lorem ipsum dwa}
    \myentry{6}{lorem ipsum tri}
\end{mylist}

\hrule

\begin{mylist}{some numbers}
    \mylinkentry{13}{bad luck}{item.one}
    \mylinkentry{665}{neighbour of the beast}{item.two}
    \mylinkentry{1337}{deep magic wizard}{item.three}
\end{mylist}

\hrule

Many people believe number \hyperlink{item.one}{13} to be bad luck.\\
The code was still blinking on th screen: \hyperlink{item.two}{665...}\\
Some people just got \hyperlink{item.three}{a lot more skill} than others.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way that I can add referable labels to each of these items?

Comment: The revised version now has a `\mylinkentry` command, which will add a `\hypertagget`with the label specified. If you just want `\label`s for later `\ref` and `\pageref`, you can simply replace `\hypertarget{#3}{#2}` with `\label{#3}#2`