# How to understand and write LaTeX code?

Tags: sourcecode, learning

LaTeX is like a language. In order to write LaTeX code I have to understand the *"word"* and the *"sentences structure"*. I have searched on wiki, some LaTeX books, but they just give the LaTeX command, not how to write a LaTeX code for some specific purpose or to understand the LaTeX code.

Here is one example:

```
\renewenvironment{svgraybox}%
       {\fboxsep=12pt\relax
        \begin{shaded}%
        \list{}{\leftmargin=12pt\rightmargin=2\leftmargin\leftmargin=\z@\topsep=\z@\relax}%
        \expandafter\item\parindent=\svparindent
        \hskip-\listparindent}%
       {\endlist\end{shaded}}%
%
\renewenvironment{svtintedbox}%
       {\fboxsep=12pt\relax
        \begin{tinted}%
        \list{}{\leftmargin=12pt\rightmargin=2\leftmargin\leftmargin=\z@\topsep=\z@\relax}%
        \expandafter\item\parindent=\svparindent
        \relax}%
       {\endlist\end{tinted}}%
%
}}
%
\let\SVMonoOpt\@empty
```

I do not know what is `\z@`, what is `\relax`, what is `\fboxsep` ... and if I want to design my LaTeX file in my own form, I know that I have to understand many other things.

Note that I can write simple LaTeX enviroment in mathematics (like the matrix, align, enviroment) but it does not help me to understand the above code.

So, what could I do? What book should I read? Or what programming language should I learn?

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192/5001). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at the posting [Where do I start LaTeX programming?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12668/5001) and the associated answers.

Comment: I think you should start with the TeXbook by Donald Knuth. It explains things like relax and the @ symbol. TeX is a programming language by itself.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay Thanks. I have looked at Knuth's book. But there are a lot of informations that lie out side that book. If I remember correctly, that book does not say much about parameter :)

Comment: Run `texdoc source2e` from the command prompt (or use the gui alternative `texdoctk`). That has all the LaTeX command definitions.

Answer (score 26):

The TeXbook is the best place to learn about the underlying TeX language, although TeX-by-Topic (`texdoc texbytopic`) in most distributions is a good free alternative. But much of what you show is not directly using TeX primitives but using constructs such as `\list` defined in the latex format. The LaTeX Companion has detail for that or the free documented sources of LaTeX `texdoc source2e` has lots of information.

This site of course can also be used. For example

- on `\z@` [What does \z@ do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55400/what-does-z-do/55401#55401)
- on list parameters, several answers, e.g., [How to create a custom list and \item element?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28593/how-to-create-a-custom-list-and-item-element)
- on `\relax` for example [What is the difference between \relax and {}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/what-is-the-difference-between-relax-and/86396#86396)
- on `\expandafter` lots of questions, e.g., [When to use \edef, \noexpand, and \expandafter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451/when-to-use-edef-noexpand-and-expandafter) but note the usage in the code you show is in error, it is harmless but does nothing.

Comment: What I want for Christmas this year is ‘Tex and LaTex Programming for Dummies’ by David Carlisle. =8-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You should write it. I (and many others) would buy it.

Answer (score 17):

You can find out what any command does by asking LaTeX itself. Just open up a console window and run `latex` (or whatever variant you prefer), and then you can issue commands line by line.

For example, to find out what `\z@` means, you can use

```
$ latex
**\makeatletter
*\show\z@
```

and LaTeX will give you

```
> \z@=\dimen12.
```

(The `\makeatletter` command allows you to use the `@` sign in commands.)

If you want to find out what length is stored in `\dimen12`, you can then use

```
*\showthe\dimen12
```

which will give you

```
> 0.0pt
```

So the `\z@` command is a short hand for a zero length.

The `\show` command will tell you the definition of any command except a primitive; you can look those up online with a Google search.

Comment: Thank ChrisS for your answer. I need to understand the LaTex essentially, systematically, but I still do not know what is \show, \makeatletter,... and there will be many other things. So thank for your answer, but I do not think that is a good idea for my case :)

Comment: This is a valid solution when you know a command and you wanna check what it does. But what about the contrary? What if you want to do *something* and I need to know the command?
Please note that this is no attack, I really like your answer (Infact I voted it up). But as a beginner latex enthusiast I exactly understand what the questioner is talking about!
I think the question is not about a specific command but a general approach.

Comment: @Pouya you really need a book "latex by topic" (by analogy with "tex by topic").  sadly, there is no such thing; and "just now", with the work on a new latex (latex 3) underway, is probably not the time to start.  for myself, i learned latex by reading sources (originally latex2.09, back in the 90s) and have learned more as latex has evolved.