# Itemizing elements with a fixed label

Tags: enumerate, itemize

I saw a  very similar question here 
[How to create a custom list and \item element?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28593/how-to-create-a-custom-list-and-item-element)

I want to have

```
\begin{mylist}{Person}
     \myentry {Jack}
     \myentry {John}
\end{mylist}
```

to produce

```
Person 1 Jack
Person 2 John
```

it would be better if instead of \myentry I can use item, and if it is possible to get rid of { } around the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found this,

```
\usepackage{enumitem} 

\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Person \arabic*:]
\item 5 + 7 = 12
\item 9 + 1 = 10
\item 2 * 2 = 4
\end{enumerate}
```